# Trying to prove that neither $P(A|B)+P(A|B')=1$ nor $P(A|B)+P(A'|B')=1$ in general

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to write out these proofs and thought the best way to proceed might be via a proof by contradiction.

Here's what I did for the first assertion, $P(A|B)+P(A|B')≠1$: 
Suppose that A and B are independent. We know then that $P(A|B)=P(A)$ and $P(A|B')=P(A)$. This implies $2P(A)=1$, which is highly unlikely unless $P(A)=0.5$.

For the second assertion, $P(A|B)+P(A'|B')≠1$, I used an example of disjoint events A and B. If $P(AnB)=0$ and $P(A|B)=0$ and $P(B|A)=0$, then that implies P(A|B)+P(A'|B')=0+P(A')=1. My contention is that this is highly unlikely if B has not occurred and P(A)≠0.

My question is the following: Am I going about this proof in the right way? I started out using Bayes' Rule but found that overcomplicated these proofs, so I thought a proof by counterexample might be simpler. However, I'm not sure if I've gone far enough or have been thorough enough in my proofs. Am I supposing too much and sacrificing thoroughness and formality, or is my method sufficiently clear and thorough?

Comment: Instead of "highly unlikely", maybe you could use a particular counterexample?

Comment: "highly unlikely unless $P(A)=0.5$" I would say "impossible".

Comment: For the first assertion, maybe I could set the counter-example to P(A)=0.6 (which would break the equality); for the second, could I just say that unless P(A)=0, the equality doesn't hold? Does that go far enough?

Comment: EDIT: Arthur, I'll just change that to impossible, then.

Comment: Quote: "If $P(A\cap B)=0$ (then) $P(A|B)=0$ ... (hence) ... $P(A|B)+P(A'|B')=0+P(A')$" Why?